# Pasar parámetros por referencia de LUA a C++

Tags: c++, lua

Supongamos que publico en LUA una función que recibe una metatabla y quiero modificar dicha tabla desde C++:

```
int operar(lua_State *L)
{
    std::vector<int> valores{};

    if (auto length = get_length_at_index(L, 1))
    {
        valores.reserve(length);

        lua_pushnil(L);
        while (lua_next(L, 1))
        {
            valores.push_back(lua_tointeger(L, -1));
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }

    for (auto &v : valores)
    {
        v *= 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto L = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "operar", operar);
    luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior lee el script `"lua.script"` que tiene el siguiente aspecto:

```
valores = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
operar(valores)

for index = 1, #valores do
    print(valores[index])
end
```

La salida esperada serían los valores del 1 al 6 multiplicados por 2, pero los valores se mantienen inalterados. Es obvio que esto suceda pues **copio** la metatabla de entrada en un vector y opero sobre la copia.

¿Existe alguna manera de operar desde C++ sobre objetos de LUA y que estos sean sensibles a las operaciones realizadas?

---

PD: Se que puedo devolver la metatabla como retorno de la función, pero quiero saber si existe otra opción.

Comment: `result` y `valores` se refiere a la misma variable?

Comment: Si, fallo mío al copiar de código real a ejemplo simplificado para SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (size_t i=0; i<valores.size(); i++)
{
    auto& v = valores[i];
    v *= 2;
    lua_pushinteger(L,v);
    lua_rawseti(L,1,i+1);
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es cargar los nuevos valores en la pila y a continuación hacer que los nuevos valores sustituyan a los antiguos... no he encontrado un mecanismo que permita recuperar los elementos por referencia.